# i have a error on my custom endpoint by a request of MariaDB

Tags: java, mariadb

I would like mapping two columns so I create a java class (pojo) with the both elements (id and test1)

```
package com.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;

public class TestRequestDB {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @Column(name = "`id`")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("test1")
    @Column(name = "`test1`")
    private String test1;

    public TestRequestDB(Long id, String test1) {
        this.id = id;
        this.test1 = test1;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTest1() {
        return test1;
    }

    public void setTest1(String test1) {
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
    
}
```

after that I created a new repository with my request :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB(t.id, t.test1) FROM test t WHERE id = 1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TestRequestDB> getTestV2();
```

and my controller :

```
@GetMapping("/findAllV2")
    ResponseEntity<List<TestRequestDB>> findAllAnnounceV2() {
        List<TestRequestDB> response_ = testRepository.getTestV2();
        if(response_.size() > 0)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response_, HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response_, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
```

the error :

```
2023-08-14T18:00:10.739+02:00  WARN 23742 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2023-08-14T18:00:10.739+02:00 ERROR 23742 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : (conn=147) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB(t.id, t.test1) FROM test t W...' at line 1
2023-08-14T18:00:10.756+02:00 ERROR 23742 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api_dev] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [SELECT new com.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB(t.id, t.test1) FROM test t WHERE id = 1] [(conn=147) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB(t.id, t.test1) FROM test t W...' at line 1] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=147) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB(t.id, t.test1) FROM test t W...' at line 1
```

but for me the request is ok because on terminal it work normally

```
MariaDB [backServerRpImmo]> select t.id, t.test1 from test t where id = 1;
+----+-------+
| id | test1 |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 1     |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0,000 sec)
```

but I can't get the result a loot at a solution during 1 week's (after my work day) but I can't fix it... Can you help me please if you need any else don't hesitate

ps : it's maven 3.1.2 and java 17

Make a endpoint Ir's a test but I would like mapping data for a table on database to make some request different of them by default

** EDIT

I had activated the log trace for the request on MariaDB, and I use another project who work normally :
Example :

`@Query(value = "SELECT new com.backEnd.coachingval.coachingval.model.Products(p.uuid, p.name, p.optn, p.price, p.ref, p.plans, p.promo, p.pricePromo) from Products p WHERE p.plans.id=:id ORDER BY p.name") List<Products> getProductsByID(@Param(value = "id") int id);`

without `nativeQuery = true` and the request on the log of MariaDb is good :

`select products0_.uuid as col_0_0_, products0_.name as col_1_0_, products0_.optn as col_2_0_, products0_.price as col_3_0_, products0_.ref as col_4_0_, products0_.plans_id as col_5_0_, products0_.promo as col_6_0_, products0_.price_promo as col_7_0_ from products products0_ inner join plans plans1_ on products0_.plans_id=plans1_.id where products0_.plans_id=1 order by products0_.name`

The request is good, but when a add `nativeQuery = true` a get this request on mariaDB log :

`SELECT new com.backEnd.coachingval.coachingval.model.Products(p.uuid, p.name, p.optn, p.price, p.ref, p.plans, p.promo, p.pricePromo) from Products p WHERE p.plans.id=1 ORDER BY p.name`

So I need to remove `nativeQuery = true` but on my actual project with the problem, when a removed `nativeQuery = true` I get this error and I don't know how a can fix it

`Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testController' defined in file [/home/kevin/Desktop/rpImmo/back_RPimmo/target/classes/com/rpImmo/BackServer/controllers/TestController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository' defined in com.rpImmo.BackServer.repository.TestRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract com.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB com.rpImmo.BackServer.repository.TestRepository.getTestV2(); Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract com.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB com.rpImmo.BackServer.repository.TestRepository.getTestV2()`

someone can help me please, thanks

Comment: *"for me the request is ok because on terminal it works normally"* You are not testing the same query.

Comment: Please read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select/ -> Select Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Sir,

I think that you do not want this part:

> new com.rpImmo.BackServer.payload.request.TestRequestDB(t.id, t.test1)

nativeQuery = true means that you are trying to execute native sql to hydrate your pojo, so the test you are doing is not the same sql that JPA is executing.

Along those lines, consider logging the SQL out to see what exactly is being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a JPQL class-based projection with a native query. That is not supported. Native queries use the SQL syntax of the DBMS, and "SELECT NEW..." is not valid SQL. The [documentation on class-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.dtos) says:

> And it’s important to point out that class-based projections do not work with native queries AT ALL.

You need to use a non-native query. When you tried, you got a different error. That error is not JPA-related, but it's a Spring error saying it can't find a suitable bean to inject into your method. You should look at Spring documentation to understand what that error means and define a suitable bean.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should remove package name from query. Also verify the JPA query documentation. Your query is a mix of SQL with JPA Query Language.

Try removing new and package. Also remove projection from columns.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-streaming

For that you should implement into your @Repository a simple method.

Example:

```
 List<TestRequestDB> findAllTestRequestDBById(Long id)
```

Comment: He's using a native query, not JPA.